# Display information depending on drop down selection - MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Product Model like this

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ProductTypeFlag ProductType { get; set; }

    public string BikeMake { get; set; }
    public string BikeModel { get; set; }

    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }

    public string TrainMake { get; set; }
    public string TrainModel { get; set; }
}

public enum ProductTypeFlag
{
    Bike = 0,
    Car = 1,
    Train = 2
}
```

As you can see, I only have three products to choose from: bike, car or train.

My Create New Product View is currently looking like this ... where I have a drop down list selection for ProductType

[image: Create View]

```html
@model WebApplication14.Models.ProductViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ProductViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.ProductType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BikeMake, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BikeMake, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BikeMake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BikeModel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BikeModel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BikeModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarMake, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarMake, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarMake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarModel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarModel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainMake, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainMake, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainMake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainModel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainModel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Now, what I want to do is, only display Product information that is relevant to selected product. For example, if I select Bike as a product then I only want to see the BikeMake and BikeModel available - i.e. I do not want to see Car/Train-Make&Model to be there as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the properties related to each vehicle type in a container div and conditionally hide/show based on the selection from the dropdown.

For example

```
<div my-section="section-0" style="display:none;">
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BikeMake, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BikeMake, new { @class = "form-control" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BikeMake)
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div my-section="section-1" style="display:none;">
   <!-- Inputs for code car related fields goes here -->
</div>
<div my-section="section-2" style="display:none;">
   <!-- Inputs for Train related fields goes here -->
</div>
```

And now listen to the change event on your SELECT element and show only that container div.

```
$(function () {

    // Show the section for the current(default) selection of the dropdown
    var t = $("#ProductType").val();  
    var item = $("[my-section='section-" + t + "']").show();

    // Wire up change event code for dropdown
    $("#ProductType").change(function (e) {
        // Hide all the sections (including previously shown)
        $("[my-section]").hide();

        //Select only the section corresponding the the dropdown selection
        var item = $("[my-section='section-" + $(this).val() + "']").show(); 
    })
});
```

For example, If you select the second item in your dropdown, The jQuery selector  code `$("[my-section='section-" + $(this).val() + "']")` will return the div with `my-section` attribute value set to `"section-1"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. But, I am still learning the basic of JQuery. Can you please explain line-by-line of what the script does?

Comment: Added some comments to the code in answer to understand it easily

Comment: in this line: var t = $("#ProductType").val(); how does jquery knows what product I select? Is #ProductType represents an div with ID equal #ProductType? I don't have that. I know you mention something about default...but I didn't quite grasp that.

Comment: ` $("#ProductType").val()` returns the selected option's value attribute value (0,1 or 2). and we are appending that to "section-" which will give us a string  like "section-1" and then we use a jQuery selector to get all elements with `my-section` attribute value set to "section-1" ( the div for car). and call the `show()` method which displays the div ( and it's content)

Comment: Thank you for explain all that. But, I still don't understand what is the #ProductType in this line  $("#ProductType").val()? Is MVC5 automatically create a div and is hidding somewhere with id=ProductType for the View in this case since I have a item called ProductType? Or is the # before the ProductType has some other meaning?

Comment: Yes. But what is #ProductType? And where does it define?

Comment: Your current code in the view generates a SELECT element with Id "ProductType" (same as property name). You use that with `#` to do  jQuery selection (to a get a ref to that DOM Element) . I suggest you read the basics of jQuery selectors.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help. So #ProductType indeed a div and is crated by MVC in this case. And you are right, I am very very new to jquery and I am omw still learning the basic of it. Thanks again!